# Is it possible in Pubnub to subscribe via javascript and publish via python

Tags: javascript, python, publish, pubnub

I am developing a dashboard application with Pubnub and EON Charts. Since my raw data lives in openstack I have to use python ceilometer API to get the data and then I am publishing the data via python and I think I will have to subscribe via Javascript since EON library is in Javascript. My question is: Is that possible to publish via one framework and subscribe via another. Is there any example documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very much possible. In fact, that is the advantage of using [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com). You can take advantage of the fact that we support so many different platforms - [70+ SDKs](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/) including iOS, Android, JavaScript, .NET, Java, Ruby, Python, PHP and many more. We have had so many examples of this. For instance, a Raspberry Pi(python) publishing sensor readings to a browser(Javascript) to visualize it using Eon.

Some examples you can look at are :

- [Triggering Raspberry Pi Hue LEDs from Android UI](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/trigger-raspberry-pi-hue-leds-from-android-ui/)
- [Remote Control Raspberry Pi LEDs from a Web Browser UI](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/remote-control-raspberry-pi-leds-from-a-web-browser-ui/)

The basic idea is that you publish on a channel, and subscribe to that channel. As long as you send a message, irrespective of the language/platform you use, you will be able to receive it. It doesn't matter whether you are publishing/subscribing to/from a device, mobile or PC, as long as you use PubNub.

So in your example specifically, as you mentioned, you will be publishing the data using our [python SDK](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk) and be using [Eon](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/) to subscribe, which is a Javascript library. Eon provides a very simple way to subscribe and create great realtime charts.

You can find a lot more examples on our [blog](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/).

Comment: Thanks! Bhavana, When I study [EON library] (https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart/tree/master/examples) I can only see the publish option, is there Subscribe option there as well? Or the code flow would be like I subscribe to a channel and then use publish to publish the message?

Comment: Say you consider the https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart/blob/master/examples/simple.html, the publish you see is simulating some values that will be subscribed by Eon.  If you look at the Simple Example in https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart, you will notice how Eon takes care of the subscribe. All you need to do is publish messages to the same channel and they'll render in the graph.